# ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems

I am just trying to generate a PDF report using `wkhtmltopdf` but for whatever reason I am getting the following error in the Rails log (when running production):

```
F, [2020-03-20T11:44:46.046955 #15784] FATAL -- : [cf46a95f-bb32-4889-ae71-6151832cba82] ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow (ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow):                                        [146/1915]
F, [2020-03-20T11:44:46.047059 #15784] FATAL -- : [cf46a95f-bb32-4889-ae71-6151832cba82]
F, [2020-03-20T11:44:46.047209 #15784] FATAL -- : [cf46a95f-bb32-4889-ae71-6151832cba82] actionpack (5.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:649:in `commit'
[cf46a95f-bb32-4889-ae71-6151832cba82] actionpack (5.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:484:in `[]='
[cf46a95f-bb32-4889-ae71-6151832cba82] actionpack (5.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:106:in `set_cookie'
[cf46a95f-bb32-4889-ae71-6151832cba82] rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:363:in `commit_session'
[cf46a95f-bb32-4889-ae71-6151832cba82] rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:234:in `context'
[cf46a95f-bb32-4889-ae71-6151832cba82] rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'
[cf46a95f-bb32-4889-ae71-6151832cba82] actionpack (5.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:670:in `call'
[cf46a95f-bb32-4889-ae71-6151832cba82] actionpack (5.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
[cf46a95f-bb32-4889-ae71-6151832cba82] activesupport (5.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
[cf46a95f-bb32-4889-ae71-6151832cba82] actionpack (5.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
[cf46a95f-bb32-4889-ae71-6151832cba82] actionpack (5.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:61:in `call'
[cf46a95f-bb32-4889-ae71-6151832cba82] actionpack (5.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
[cf46a95f-bb32-4889-ae71-6151832cba82] railties (5.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
[cf46a95f-bb32-4889-ae71-6151832cba82] railties (5.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
[cf46a95f-bb32-4889-ae71-6151832cba82] activesupport (5.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
[cf46a95f-bb32-4889-ae71-6151832cba82] activesupport (5.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
[cf46a95f-bb32-4889-ae71-6151832cba82] activesupport (5.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
[cf46a95f-bb32-4889-ae71-6151832cba82] railties (5.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
[cf46a95f-bb32-4889-ae71-6151832cba82] actionpack (5.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
[cf46a95f-bb32-4889-ae71-6151832cba82] actionpack (5.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
[cf46a95f-bb32-4889-ae71-6151832cba82] rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
[cf46a95f-bb32-4889-ae71-6151832cba82] rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
[cf46a95f-bb32-4889-ae71-6151832cba82] activesupport (5.2.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
[cf46a95f-bb32-4889-ae71-6151832cba82] actionpack (5.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
[cf46a95f-bb32-4889-ae71-6151832cba82] actionpack (5.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'
[cf46a95f-bb32-4889-ae71-6151832cba82] rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
[cf46a95f-bb32-4889-ae71-6151832cba82] railties (5.2.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
[cf46a95f-bb32-4889-ae71-6151832cba82] passenger (6.0.4) src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:97:in `process_request'
[cf46a95f-bb32-4889-ae71-6151832cba82] passenger (6.0.4) src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:157:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
```

I have run across other solutions and many of them start off with having you run `rake db:sessions:create`

but this command does not work for me -- I get the following error:

```
# RAILS_ENV=production rake db:sessions:create
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'db:sessions:create' (See the list of available tasks with `rake --tasks`)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

To my knowledge, I don't see why `wkhtmltopdf` would be doing *anything* with the cookie. My partials are just rendering data being obtained from ActiveRecord's database.

Any thoughts as to why this may be happening and how to resolve it? I am using Rails 5.2.3

Comment: My initial though is that wkhtmltopdf  is a red herring. You need to audit your code and check where you are using the session - usually its something like stuffing entire objects into the session as a lazy debugging effort or stuffing an entire API response into the session. If that does not narrow down the error you need to expand the audit down to your dependencies. `rake db:sessions:create` is to create the sessions table in older versions of Rails that stored sessions in the database and won't do anything to fix a cookie overflow.

Comment: Take care to ensure your post title is spelled properly.

Comment: You can try a hello world PDF and see if wkhtmltopdf is using cookie. This `rake db:sessions:create` is provided by this gem: https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store. You need to install the gem to have it.

Comment: I have the same problem using Rails 6.1 - CookieOverflow error when my code is doing nothing explicit with cookies and the traceback throws no light on the matter at all as it cant be traced to any specific line in my code seemingly originating in gems/puma-3.12.6/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread' or somewhere deeper in the stack.
It doesnt make any sense and it seems an overhead to rework the code to handle cookies > 4K when I shouldnt need to.
Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Found my problem to the above. I was accidentally writing an object collection to the Flash message which seemingly uses CookieStore,

Once I identified and fixed this my CookieOverflow problem disappeared, Mea culpa.